# Remove unnecessary comma separator.. 1 comma per word

Tags: php, mysql, select, concatenation

This is my remarks column

```
       remarks
   ,jsedfedf,, 
   , late,, , example
   example2, ,, example4
```

Im just new to mysql.. how could I remove unnecessary comma?..
and make it like this?

```
       remarks
    jsedfedf
    late, example
    example2, example4
```

Comment: remarks
    jsedfedf?

Comment: Do you know user3114385? Your table looks a lot like the one in his questions?

Comment: Why are you putting all those extra commas in the field in the first place?

Comment: If it's coming from `GROUP_CONCAT` in your previous question, try replacing the blank remarks with `NULL`. `GROUP_CONCAT` ignores null values, so you won't get any blanks.

Comment: The `NULLIF` function will be useful for that.

Comment: @user3117337 If you are [user3114385](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3114385/user3114385), log in to your other account and see the messages i left for you. why are you creating multiple accounts anyways?

Answer (score 1):

Split the strings by `,` and then concatenate them using `,`.

Consecutive `,` and `,` at the beginning and end would give empty strings which you don't need to add to your string.